# magento2 CatalogSearch ResultController params missing

Tags: magento2

[image]Under **\Tagalys\Tglssearch\Controller\CatalogSearch\ResultController.php**

```
class ResultController extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index
{
   public function execute()   
   {
      $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();   
    $response = array(); 
    //Custom Change End

    //$query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data')->checkNotes();

    $this->layerResolver->create(Resolver::CATALOG_LAYER_SEARCH);
    $query = $this->_queryFactory->get();    


    /* @var $query Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query */

    //$query->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $query->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());  

    if ($query->getQueryText() != '')
    {
        //if (Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->isMinQueryLength()) {
        if ($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Search\Helper\Data')->isMinQueryLength())
        {
              $query->setId(0)
                ->setIsActive(1)
                ->setIsProcessed(1); 
         }
```

why does the $query variable does not include "is_active" "is_processed" params

Below is the output in magento1x from class Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query Object , but for Magento2x i get from Magento\Search\Model\Query Object hence im not getting the above params like is_active.

[image]